# Calculate product of two numbers when numbers are not availble in sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables @tbl_numshr that contains number of shares for each security or stock and @tbl_shrprice that contains 
 price for each day for particular stock.

I want to find out each day marketcap that is nosshare*shrprice but the problem is, in table @tbl_numshr i dont have nosshare for each day but in 
 @tbl_shrprice i have each day entry for each stock.

Table @tbl_numshr contains data whenver it changes due to some company actions on particular stock hence i want to consider old data till new data for new date is not availble.

please help in this case.

```
declare @tbl_numshr table (id int identity ,sharecode int,  nosshare float , logdate datetime )


declare @tbl_shrprice table(id int identity ,sharecode int , shrprice float, logdate datetime)


insert into @tbl_numshr (sharecode,nosshare,logdate)
values(1000, 1200.5,'2016-02-10'),(1000, 2100,'2016-02-17'),(1000, 2500,'2016-12-23')

insert into @tbl_shrprice (sharecode,shrprice,logdate)
values(1000, 10,'2016-01-01') , (1000, 12,'2016-01-02'),(1000, 18,'2016-01-03')
```

Comment: Look into using a calendar table.

Comment: I assume, that: `noshare` was equal to 1200.5 from 10th of Feb. until 17th of Feb. when it changed to 2100, then it was equal 2100 until 23rd of Dec., when it chsanged again to 2500? If so, was equal to 0 before 10th of Feb.?

Comment: no it should be equal to 1200.5

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes there is calendar table but if i join calendar table with tbl_numshr  it would only return matching data, i want to generate  complete sequence i can do it using cte but if there are only one start and one end on this case every missing things need to be generate.

Comment: Are you using left join from the calendar table?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`APPLY`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx), as it allows correlated subqueries with `TOP(1)` and `ORDER BY`:

```
insert into @tbl_shrprice (sharecode,shrprice,logdate)
values(1000, 10,'2016-02-10') , (1000, 12,'2016-02-20'),(1000, 18,'2016-02-25')

select p.*, np.nosshare, p.shrprice * np.nosshare as marketcap
from @tbl_shrprice p
cross apply (
    select top(1) *
    from @tbl_numshr n
    where n.sharecode = p.sharecode
    and n.logdate <= p.logdate
    order by logdate desc
) as np
```

Note that correlated `APPLY` has a significant cost for *large datasets*. I modified the dates of the prices so they actually make sense when correlated with the number of shares.